# What are these rhombus/triangles around the neck?

Tags: culture

I saw these rhombus/triangles around the neck in a few stories but do not know what it is:

- *I'm Not the Evil God's Lackey* character - Original Witch Silver

  [image] [image]
- *I'm the Grim Reaper* (webtoon) character - Satan

  [image] [image]

What are these?

Answer (score 2):

For the first character, it appears to be a geometric [choker](https://www.google.com/search?q=choker&tbm=isch), while on the second character, I'm willing to bet it's a scar going around their neck. I've seen scars depicted as beveled diamonds in a row like that, and there are other [anime characters with similar scarring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dio_Brando) which the artist likely took inspiration from,  but these are just my initial musings upon skimming stories and looking at character designs, I could be completely off.